# how to store types as variables and use them in parameters' type?

Tags: c#

```
class constType
{
    public static const Type messageType = typeof(int); // HOW TO DO THIS? 1st mark

    public string[] GetArraySomehow()
    {
        return new string[sizeof(messageType)]; // HOW TO DO THIS? 2nd mark
    }
}

class testTypeInClass
{
    public void test(constType.messageType message) // HOW TO DO THIS? 3rd mark
    {

    }
}
```

Okay so this is really weird and strange I know but how can I do this?

- **1st mark:** I have to store int's type as const variable and use it laterç
- **2nd mark:** I have to get stored type's size (how many bytes does it equal?)
- **3rd mark:** I have to use it as a parameter type.

Well Why I have to do this such thing:

I have to store a type (not so wide, just I know I'll use int8,16,32 etc)
and have to know what exactly bytes does it equal (1,2,4 etc..);

well first of all I have a method in one of my classes which uses switch statement and:

like this:

```
  public string test (int messageIndex)
    {
        switch (messageIndex)
        {
            case 0:
                return "etc.. etc..";
            case 1231412:
                return "whatever";
        }
    }
```

Firstly I had some method like this:

```
public int fixForSwitchStatement(byte[] messageIndex)
    {
        byte[] RValue = new byte[4];

        for (int i = 0; i <= messageIndex.Length - 1; i++)
        {
            RValue[i] = messageIndex[i];
        }
        for (int i = messageIndex.Length; i <= 4 - messageIndex.Length - 1; i++)
        {
            RValue[i] = 0;
        }

        return BitConverter.ToInt32(RValue, 0);
    }
```

I was passing byte or short to switch statement then I was converting to int (int was a specified type for me) and I wanted to make a redesign like this.

```
public string test (/* [what's the case limit? that I've determined?] */ messageIndex)
    {
        switch (messageIndex)
        {
            case 0:
                return "etc.. etc..";
            case 1231412:
                return "whatever";
        }
    }
```

Because I don't want to use fixSwitch... method anymore. I just need a specified type for all of these concept.

Why I have to use fixSwitch instead of typecasting like (int)somethingByte?

Well in my one of classes there is a thing called communicationSize, its the messageIndex thing's maximum size in byte(s) that I have to declare. This is for my server-client project. There is a messageIndex thing being used as a request index what server and client requests from each other. And I'm limiting it with byte(s). For save some data space from connection.

```
// still is being written
```

Comment: What is your actual use case? I'm sure we can provide a better way to go than that.

Comment: some C language smell :) what you trying to achieve here ?

Comment: I dont' know C btw, This is my 2nd language (1st was VB.NET). It's so hard to explain why I have to need this such thing but I'm on my way to explain.

Comment: If you can't explain, then we won't be able to help. I suspected you might want to use generics, but without more details I can't provide any example/advice.

Comment: Please try to write the question as a use case that answers what you want to do instead of how you want to do it.

Comment: It seems you don't want to make that constant static. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/79b3xss3%28v=vs.80%29.aspx

Comment: ok, but consider 1. What should come up from the function you describe? I mean if one in int32: 4 byte, long: 16... ? Or you need to find minimum possible type where the given number can fit ?

Comment: The function is just converting byte to int. but there is a specified limit in my class Its 4 (I didn't add this to my example) You should probably say why just dont use (int)somethingByte but It's not like this

Comment: @haxxoromer Why do you need all this stuff? If your method declaration is `public string test (int messageIndex)`, then you could pass a `byte`, `short` or `int` as `messageIndex`. There is an implicit cast from those types to `int`.

Comment: @haxxoromer I still don't get it, still unclear to me what you try to achieve. What are the possible values for `messageIndex` you want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what the goal is and the question has been edited in the meantime but heres some example code using generics that may help you further.

```
class constType<T> where T : struct
{
    public T GetT()
    {
        return new T();
    }

    public string[] GetArraySomehow()
    {
        var len = Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(T));
        return new string[len];
    }
}

class testTypeInClass
{
    public void test<T>(T message) where T : struct
    {

    }
}

class MyClass
{
    void Test()
    {
        var constType = new constType<int>();

        var typeInClass = new testTypeInClass();

        var t = constType.GetT();

        typeInClass.test(t);

    }
}
```

Comment: Firstly thanks for post, anyways I'm going to do this with generics just wondered whether it could be done in someway that I've posted